# How to NSLog with \n\r\t

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nslog

In my application I am reading an HTML page to a string. HTML Page contains many tags, new lines & many other characters.

```
<style type="text/css">
    h3{ 
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:18px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px; 
        text-align:justify; 
        color:black; 
        background-color:transparent;
        width:280px;
        margin:0;
    }

    body{ 
        font-weight:normal;
        line-height:18px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px; 
        text-align:justify; 
        color:black; 
        background-color:transparent;
        width:280px;
    }
</style>
```

I want to replace this string like following.
When we NSLog above HTML page, it will print as above looks. But What I want to NSLog is as follows

```
\t\t<style type="text/css">\n\t\t\th3{\n
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:18px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px; 
        text-align:justify; 
        color:black; 
        background-color:transparent;
        width:280px;
        margin:0;
    }

    body{ 
        font-weight:normal;
        line-height:18px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:12px; 
        text-align:justify; 
        color:black; 
        background-color:transparent;
        width:280px;
    }
</style>
```

I mean including backslash characters. Is it possible? The reason behind this - I want to replace above style dynamically - but for replacing above I must have source to replace - How to get source including \n&\r characters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6).  You'll need something like:

```
string = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesofString: @"\n" withString: @"\\n"];
// repeat for \t  and \r
```